# Arc Hydro Vector Ruggedness Measure giving "invalid characters" error

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arc-hydro, error-000354

I'm trying to use the Arc Hydro toolbox (https://www.esri.com/en-us/industries/water-resources/arc-hydro/downloads).
I'm using a DEM as my input for the Vector Ruggedness Measure tool.
However, the tool keeps failing and I receive this error:

[image]

I've tried a couple of different things including:

1. changing file name
2. trying different versions of this dem (unaltered and de-trended)
3. using other DEMs in different projects

Any advice?

Comment: Please always provide errors as formatted text rather than only in a picture.

Comment: What is the full folder path for your DEM and your output? What is the full path to your project? (where the temporary files are likely to be created)

Comment: Could you share the settings you used?

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: I scraped the project I was working in and created a new project. The tool worked after that.